# I need to get pip but don't have disutils

Tags: linux, unix, pip

I need to get disutils.util to unpackage things that I try to get using pip. The problem is I don't have pip and I don't have permission to use sudo or basically anything.

I searched and searched but I couldn't find a solution that worked.

I'm on Linux the 18.04 LTS I have python 3.

Comment: I think pip can install locally.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: ya im using the bionic beaver LTS version